# How can I display a decorated swing window yet still keep it transparent in >JDK8?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I have seen that java can display translucent windows. But I soon noticed, that they have to be "undecorated", which I need to avoid.

I an aware that somewhere in the Documentation it is mentioned, that this behavior is impossible, yet still I have seen this before.

I don't care if Java 8 / JDK 8 has this feature built in (somewhere) or if I have to use a 3rd party API. I don't really care. It just has to work.

There is a (maybe outdated, I don't really know) [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html) that shows, that it's possible (illustrated below).

[image]

---

**I use the NetBeans form designer. That might also be a limiting factor. How can I achieve this functionality in JDK 8? Or which 3rd party library do I have to use to accomplish this behavior?**

EDIT:
I now know that this is the Metal look and feel. But is there any way to get the Windows Look and feel transparent WITH the Name bar and the X and so on.

Comment: I
 if you pore in the properties section of the form you will find an option where you can control the percentage of opaque. That should do it I guess because I have done the same with JavaFX while using JDK 8.

Comment: @JosephMwema This doesn't work for me. I got this `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException: The frame is decorated`. I didn't expect it to, either.

Comment: Generally, you can't the examples are misleading. The only way you can get this to work is to use the "default" (metal) look and feel (or a look and feel which supplies the window decorations itself)